# mysql trigger after insert update value on different table

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I'm trying to do a song voting system:

imagine i have these tables in my database:

table 'songs'
  song_id(PRIMARY)
  song_name
  song_artist
  song_votes

table 'votes'
  vote_id(PRIMARY)
  iddevice
  song_id

table 'users'
  iddevice(PRIMARY)

the table USERS, only register the id of the device.

the table sonts, register info about songs.

the table votes, is created to make sure every unique device can only vote once each song.

what i want to achieve is that, when a device votes a song, a new row is inserted on the VOTES table, registering the IDDEVICE of the person that votes, and the SONG_ID of the song that receives the vote.
At the same time, the field SONG_VOTES on the SONGS table, has to get updated with the new vote, and I assume this has to be done with a TRIGGER.

so, when you insert a row on VOTES table, the song referenced by that SONG_ID, has to get its SONG_VOTES field updated.

if anyone with experience in mysql could help i would really appreciate it. thx.

Comment: did not understand..could you please expand the question with some more details if possible with some example ?

Comment: yes, i will edit the question!